# Beginner: Examining Queryset results

Tags: python, django

Disclaimer: I am new to python and Django, but have Drupal programming experience.

I'm following the tutorials here (http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/), but I'm confused by

```
Publisher.objects.filter(name='Apress')
[<Publisher: Apress>]
```

I understand that the result is a Queryset Object, so how can I retrieve the address (or primary key) when the following approach fails?

```
p = Publisher.objects.filter(name='Apress')
a = p.address
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'address'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes are only available on the model instances. A `QuerySet` is simplistically just as list of model instances, so you have to "unpack" it somehow to get at a particular instance and then the attribute on that.

If you know that there's only one of the thing you're querying for, you should use `get` instead of filter:

```
publisher = Publisher.objects.get(name='Apress')
print publisher.address
```

But, if multiple matches are returned, it will raise a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception, and conversely, if no match is found an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception is raised. As a result, you need to be careful when using `get` and make sure to wrap your code in appropriate `try...except` blocks.

If you're dealing with something where you expect more than one result, then you can either use some sort of loop structure to deal with each individual item in the `QuerySet`:

```
for publisher in Publisher.objects.all():
    print publisher.address
```

Or, directly pull out one item as you would with a traditional list:

```
first_publisher = Publisher.objects.all()[0]
print first_publisher.address
```

Comment: Excellent detail Chris. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think this answer is better than mine with more details! mellow-yellow I think you can accept it! tick! :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to call the [get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) function instead:

```
p = Subject.objects.get(name='Apress')
```

Comment: Thanks Thanasis. That worked. I was afraid to use get() because it requires a single result be returned. "If there are no results that match the query, get() will raise a DoesNotExist exception." So, I suppose that objects.all() or objects.filter() result in a *list* of objects (assuming multiple matches), whereas get returns a single object.

Comment: you can add a try block to catch an exception that maybe thrown. You can find more information here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Answer (score 1):

Your QuerySet is essentially a list so you'll need to loop over each item in order to access its `address` attribute. Something like this:

```
for p in Publisher.objects.filter(name='Apress'):
    # access p.address here
```

Your syntax would work if you followed @Thanasis' advice above because using `get` returns you only one object.